Role-based authorization for action without one for controller
I am trying to implement role-based authorization on a ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, and the goal is that users have access to nothing by default. Their role has to be declared explicitly.
Another requirement is that the Admin role should have access to absolutely everything.
I struggle to see how to implement this simple cybersecurity requirement because :

If I don't add the [Authorize] attribute on the controller, then it is completely open to anyone with any role. This default behavior seems extremely weird to me, as it means if we just forget to set the Authorize attribute, we completely open our sensitive API to any user.
If I want to set a "default" role for the controller and then override it at the action level, I can't because they are additive.

I have seen various answers here on SO to deal with this but usually they either answer part of the problem or they are completely outdated and relate to ASP.NET MVC, or they deal about making stuff just public/not public.
What I would like is this :
public class AppController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public IActionResult ListItems() {} // <= Can be accessed by role "User"

    public IActionResult GetItem() {} // <= Can be accessed by no one
}

As an alternative, it would be acceptable for us to have this :
[Authorize("Admin")]
public class AppController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public IActionResult ListItems() {} // <= Can be accessed by roles "User" OR "Admin"

    public IActionResult GetItem() {} // <= Can be accessed by "Admin"
}

But I have not seen any way to change the fact that if the role check for controller fails, it won't reach the check for the action.
Inverting the logic (User on controller and then Admin where it's due) is not OK because it brings us back to a lack of security, plus it still means that all admins need to also have the user role, which is a bit of overhead in role management.
I don't know how to get to any of these two options, I have a feeling this implies re-implementing some custom things, but I don't know which ones.

Have a read of this article that suggests how to implement dynamic policies which might achieve your outcome.

It should be
[Authorize(Roles="Admin,User")]
public class AppController : Controller
{
    
    public IActionResult ListItems() {} // <= Can be accessed by roles "User" OR "Admin"
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public IActionResult GetItem() {} // <= Can be accessed by "Admin"
}

You could read this document for more details

The issue with this is that if someone forgets to add the Admin role
on an action, all the other roles have access to it, which goes
against the "access nothing by default"

If all your authenticated users have a role,you may set a fallback plolicy follow this doc as below:
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});


Maybe it is not clear enough in my question but I am specifically asking for a way to work around the fact that I need to declare all roles on the controllers if I want to use them on the actions. The issue with this is that if someone forgets to add the Admin role on an action, all the other roles have access to it, which goes against the "access nothing by default"

You may set a fallbackpolicy follow this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-8.0#require-authenticated-users  ,hopes help

1-You can create a policy
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
});

YourController.cs
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminOnly")]
public class AdminController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult GetAdminData()
    {
        return Ok("Admin data");
    }
}

2-You can give [AllowAnonymous] if all your endpoints requires auth this will be make the endpoint accessed by everyone.
[AllowAnonymous]
public class YourController: ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult AnonymousEndpoint()
    {
        return Ok("This api is accessed by everyone");
    }
}

3-Or you can assign the roles into filter
[Authorize("Admin,User")]

Thank you for your answer but I don't think it answers my question as it does not allow to make several roles cohabit the way I described
